# Spring MVC delete using modal

Tags: java, javascript, spring, spring-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I have a problem on delete item using modal. I can delete the using just the href obtaining the id and passing it to the controller. But i dont know how to get the id of the item in modal and delete it.

List of persons and actions to be performed

```
<c:forEach var="user" items="${listpersons}">
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="#">${user.username}</a><!--  <span>Clients</span> --> </td>
                    <td><a href="#">${user.email}</a></td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="btn btn-white btn-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Compose"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i></a></button>
                        <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/edit?id=${user.id}&name=${user.username}&password=${user.password}&email=${user.email}"><i class="fa fa-edit" title="Edit"></i></a></button>
                        <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/delete?id=${user.id}" title="Delete"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
                        <a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" data-toggle="modal">Launch Demo Modal</a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-right mail-date">Jan 16</td>
                </tr>
 </c:forEach>
```

this part is the modal button when clicked pops.up a if i want to really delete the item

```
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" data-toggle="modal">Launch Demo Modal</a>
```

this is my delete button. i can delete here but i want to delete using modal

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/delete?id=${user.id}" title="Delete"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
```

and this is my modal popup

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Confirm Delete</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Are you sure you want to delete this user? </p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/delete?id=${user.id}" title="Delete"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I dont know how to pass the id of the person in the modal popup. delete doesnt work. it doent recognize any id

this is the controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/delete", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView delete(@ModelAttribute("SpringWeb")User user, ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        try
        {
            UserDao ud = new UserJDBC();
            int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
            int delete = ud.deleteUser(id);
            model.addAttribute("message", "User deleted Successfuly");

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.print(e);
            model.addAttribute("message", "Error occured in deleting user.");
        }

        return new ModelAndView("admin-view-users");
    }
```

User is not deleted. i get this delete?id=0 when clicking the Delete on the modal

Comment: Can you post the controller and the error that you are getting?

Comment: @minion, i've added the controller. I can't get the id of the person when clicking Delete inside the modal. The id is = 0.

Comment: An observation. When using spring you can use @RequestParam to get the id value. Keeping that apart, what is the url you see when you click the href in modal window? Is it same as the one that see when clicking on the non modal?

Comment: the modal button href is just #MyModal. and the delete button inside the modal is delete?id=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Append `${user.id}` with href value of popup show button i.e.

`#myModal_${user.id}`

Add modal popup inside the **foreach** loop and now append `${user.id}` with popup id.
i.e. `myModal_${user.id}`

replace your foreach with this code and remove popup.

```
<c:forEach var="user" items="${listpersons}">
<tr>
    <td><a href="#">${user.username}</a><!--  <span>Clients</span> --> </td>
    <td><a href="#">${user.email}</a></td>
    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-white btn-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Compose"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i></a></button>
        <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/edit?id=${user.id}&name=${user.username}&password=${user.password}&email=${user.email}"><i class="fa fa-edit" title="Edit"></i></a></button>
        <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/delete?id=${user.id}" title="Delete"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
        <a href="#myModal_${user.id}" role="button" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" data-toggle="modal">Launch Demo Modal</a>
    </td>
    <td class="text-right mail-date">Jan 16</td>
</tr>

<div id="myModal_${user.id}" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Confirm Delete</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Are you sure you want to delete this user? </p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/delete?id=${user.id}" title="Delete"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>Delete</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  
</c:forEach>
```

***Note:-Please do not forgot to add modal popup inside foreach.***